# How do I get Ansible to install vim-enhanced with yum

Tags: rpm, ansible, yum

Issue: I want to install the full featured vim using Ansible.

Problem: The ansible yum module fails installing vim because it conflicts with vim-minimal.  If vim-minimal is uninstalled so is the sudo package.  If the sudo package is not installed ansible cannot function properly.

Question: What is the proper way to install vim with ansible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, I am just not sure it is the Ansible way:

```
  - name: Check if vim-enhanced.rpm is installed
    command: rpm -q vim-enhanced
    register: vim_rpm_check
    changed_when: false
    failed_when: "'command not found' in vim_rpm_check.stderr"
    when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'yum'

  - name: Execute yum to install vim
    sudo: yes
    command: yum -y swap vim-minimal vim install sudo
    when: ansible_pkg_mgr == 'yum' and vim_rpm_check.stdout.find('is not installed') != -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible's yum module is very limited, and isn't capable of advanced transactions such as `yum shell` or `yum swap`.  You'll have to use the command module to do it yourself.

```
yum -y swap vim-minimal vim-enhanced
```

Comment: That is kinda what I figured.  Since I have to use the command module what is the bet way to do it in an idempotent way?  If I just use the command module won't it show changed with each run?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact way to do it in ansible, but I'd imagine you would want something like this bash snippet:

    ```rpm -q vim-enhanced || yum -y swap vim-minimal vim-enhanced```

In other words, check if vim-enhanced is installed, and if it isn't, try to swap vim-minimal for vim-enhanced.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the swap from uninstalling sudo on the way by?

Comment: It shouldn't be trying to.  By the way, I just noticed on EL7 that vim-minimal doesn't conflict with vim-enhanced.  I have both installed right now.  What distro are you using?

Comment: For {reasons} {client} is still using EL6

Comment: It's the same thing on EL6.  Neither vim-minimal or vim-enhanced have any conflicts at all, much less with each other.  You should just be able to tell ansible to install vim-enhanced, it it just work.

Comment: I'm getting conflicts: `Error: Transaction check error:
  file /usr/share/man/man1/vim.1.gz from install of vim-common-2:8.0.983-1.fc26.x86_64 conflicts with file from package vim-minimal-2:8.0.662-1.fc26.x86_64`

Comment: @FredrikWendt It appears that file moved from vim-minimal to vim-common.  Update vim-minimal first and then it will work.